# UIActivityViewController called from UITableViewCell incorrectly displayed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have a `UITableView` in a `UIViewController` that is embedded in a Navigation Controller. The `UIViewController` is arranged using Auto Layout. I am using [SWTableViewCell](https://github.com/CEWendel/SWTableViewCell) to enable swipe left-to-right. This displays a 'share' button which displays a `UIActivityViewController` when tapped.

The problem is, the `UIActivityViewController` displays incorrectly when called, squished to the left side of the view and attached to the top left corner. See images below for example, the first is during display of the `UIActivityViewController`, and the second is once the `UIActivityViewController` is displayed.

I haven't been able to find any other posts about this type of issue. The code below is how I call the `UIActivityViewController` from the `- (void)swipeableTableViewCell:(SWTableViewCell *)cell didTriggerLeftUtilityButtonWithIndex:(NSInteger)index` method of `SWTableViewCell` delegate.

```
WhatsAppMessage *whatsappMsg = [[WhatsAppMessage alloc] initWithMessage:shareItem forABID:nil];

NSArray *activityItems = @[shareItem, whatsappMsg];
NSArray *applicationActivities = @[[[JBWhatsAppActivity alloc] init],[[LINEActivity alloc] init], [[WeixinTimelineActivity alloc] init],[[WeixinSessionActivity alloc] init]];

UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:applicationActivities];

activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard, UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll, UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList, UIActivityTypePostToVimeo, UIActivityTypePostToFlickr, UIActivityTypeAirDrop];

[self.navigationController presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:^{}];
```

Any ideas?

[image: During display of UIActivityViewController][image: Once UIActivityViewController is displayed]

Comment: I've tried almost the exact same code to present a `UIActivityViewController` in a blank single view application (with and without a `UINavigationController` and it works perfectly so I must have setup something odd in my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the answer and I knew it had something to do with auto layout. Earlier in the project I had most of my auto layout constraints set in code and I had put the following line in my AppDelegate.m file:

```
    self.window.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
```

After removing this line, the `UIActivityViewController` loads perfectly!

Hopefully this helps others who run into this issue.